# Change this query so it returns NULL rows when the value doesn't exist, otherwise return the value

Tags: sql, join, null

```
SELECT
    WCC.WardCensusTypesId, M.MonthsId, WCT.WardCensusTypesName,
    Y.YearsId, WCC.WardCensusCountsNum
FROM WardCensusTypes WCT
LEFT JOIN WardCensusCounts WCC ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN Months M ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN Years Y On Y.YearsId=3
```

**WardCensusTypes** contains all the types (6 of them)

**Months** contains just a list of months (1-12)

**Years** contains formatted years (yearsid = 1 : '2010-2011', yearsid=2:'2011-2012', and so on)

**WardCensusCounts** contains a WardCensusCountsNum for each, given the monthid, YearsId, and WardCensusTypesId.

WardCensusCounts contains 1 record: WardCensusTypesId=1, MonthsId=1, YearsId=3, WardCensusCountsNum=5

When I do the big query above I get a '10' for WCC.WardCensusCountsNum for each row, the query returns 72 rows, all with the value of 10 for the WCT.WardCensusCountsNum field.  What I want is the value 10 for the 1 row that matches MonthsId, YearsId, and WardCensusTypesId, but all the other rows (71 of them) should return NULL for that field.  Is there a way to change the query to do this?

Comment: Why does it return 72 and not 144 rows (12x12) ?

Comment: I'd like to help. Can you strip this down so it's not so confusing?  Strip it down to the simplest form possible while still exhibiting the issue you'd like to resolve.  Thanks!

Comment: Oops, sorry there are 6 types, not 12.  6x12.  Just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a `LEFT JOIN` only to table `WardCensusCounts`. Since you want all combinations of the other 3 tables, `CROSS JOIN` of those 3 tables is more probably what you need:

```
SELECT
    WCT.WardCensusTypesId            --- chnaged this to WCT. (not WCC.)
  , M.MonthsId
  , WCT.WardCensusTypesName 
  , Y.YearsId
  , WCC.WardCensusCountsNum
FROM
    WardCensusTypes WCT
  CROSS JOIN
    Months M 
  CROSS JOIN
    Years Y
  LEFT JOIN
    WardCensusCounts WCC
      ON  WCC.WardCensusTypesId = WCT.WardCensusTypesId
      AND WCC.MonthsId = M.MonthsId 
      AND WCC.YearsId = Y.YearsId
WHERE Y.YearsId = 3
```

---

Regarding `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    a
  CROSS JOIN
    b
```

can also be coded (perhaps for older dbms that do not have CROSS JOIN) as:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    a
  , b
```

or like what you had (since `1=1` is always true, there is no difference if you have JOIN or LEFT JOIN):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    a
  JOIN
    b
  ON 1=1
```

Comment: ypercube, Great!  Works like a charm.  need to study more on "CROSS JOIN", haven't used that before.  Thanks again!

Comment: Note that the two cross join syntaxes are not absolutely identical. When you write `a CROSS JOIN b` then join order of `a then b` must be preserved, whereas joining with `a, b` gives the query optimiser freedom to rearrange the join for performance.

Comment: @Peter: thnx, I didn't know that.

Comment: Actually, now that I've looked at it more, it seems that not all query engines follow that. SQLite does, but I'm not sure about others.

Comment: @Peter: Searching over `CROSS JOIN` at MySQL, I found another "perl" of MySQL. One can actually use: `FROM a CROSS JOIN b ON a.id = b.id` like if it was an `INNER JOIN` ! And vice versa `FROM a INNER JOIN b`, without the `ON` clause...